# What dyes are now available in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Notch just updated the game and reintroduced dyed blocks - in the form of wool + a specific dye.

Apparently there's 15 new dyes, obtainable through various means - but I can't seem to find information on all 15.

What dyes are now available and how can I obtain them?

Comment: do you know any of them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]

#### Dyes made from items

- Yellow flower → **Dandelion Yellow**
- Red flower → **Rose Red**
- Cactus →  **Cactus Green** (Cook in furnace)
- Bone → **Bone Meal** (white dye)

#### Items usable as dye

- Squid → **Ink Sack** (black dye)
- Lapis Lazuli Ore → **Lapis Lazuli** (blue dye)
- Dungeon Chest → **Cocoa Beans** (brown dye)

#### Dyes made by combining other dyes

- Rose Red + Dandelion Yellow → **Orange Dye**
- Bone Meal + Rose Red → **Pink Dye**
- Ink Sack + Bone Meal → **Dark Grey Dye**
- Dark Grey Dye + Bone Meal → **Light Grey Dye**
- Ink Sack + Bone Meal x2 → **Light Grey Dye**
- Cactus Green + Lapis Lazuli → **Cyan Dye**
- Rose Red + Lapis Lazuli → **Purple Dye**
- Lapis Lazuli Dye + Bone Meal → **Light Blue Dye**
- Cactus Green Dye + Bone Meal → **Lime Green Dye**
- Pink Dye + Purple Dye → **Magenta Dye**

Comment: @Raven It's CW, edit it in :)

Comment: yeah, I realized that after I commented.

Comment: Not done this (hence the comment) but I would expect Purple + Bone Meal to give a lighter purple

Comment: Also Green + Bone Meal to give light green and Lapis Lazuli + Bone Meal to give light blue.

Comment: lol why does part of the pic say Starbucks Coffee?

Comment: Did anyone notice starbucks?

Answer (score 1):

As always, the minecraft wiki has the answer:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wool_Dyes

Comment: While valid, this answer is not acceptable. Referring a sources is usefull, but giving information directly here is better. You should have quoted your source, then provided the link. This way, even if your source is pining for the fjords, the info is still here...